# Dialogflow nodejs fulfilment without firebase

Tags: node.js, azure, dialogflow-es

I am trying to build my webhooks using nodejs and without using firebase.
I found a resource and built my index.js file like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {
    dialogflow
} = require('actions-on-google');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = dialogflow({
    debug: true
});
const server = express()
    .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }))
    .use(bodyParser.json(), app)
    .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));

// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'Default Welcome Intent'.
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
    const name = conv.user.storage.userName;
    if (!name) {
      // Asks the user's permission to know their name, for personalization.
      conv.ask(new Permission({
        context: 'Hi there, to get to know you better',
        permissions: 'NAME',
      }));
    } else {
      conv.ask(`Hi again, ${name}. What are you looking for?`);
    }
  });

  // Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'actions_intent_PERMISSION'. If user
  // agreed to PERMISSION prompt, then boolean value 'permissionGranted' is true.
  app.intent('actions_intent_PERMISSION', (conv, params, permissionGranted) => {
    if (!permissionGranted) {
      // If the user denied our request, go ahead with the conversation.
      conv.ask(`OK, no worries. What are you looking for?`);
      conv.ask(new Suggestions('Blue', 'Red', 'Green'));
    } else {
      // If the user accepted our request, store their name in
      // the 'conv.user.storage' object for future conversations.
      conv.user.storage.userName = conv.user.name.display;
      conv.ask(`Thanks, ${conv.user.storage.userName}. ` +
        `What are you looking for?`);
      conv.ask(new Suggestions('Blue', 'Red', 'Green'));
    }
  });

  // Handle the Dialogflow NO_INPUT intent.
  // Triggered when the user doesn't provide input to the Action
  app.intent('actions_intent_NO_INPUT', (conv) => {
    // Use the number of reprompts to vary response
    const repromptCount = parseInt(conv.arguments.get('REPROMPT_COUNT'));
    if (repromptCount === 0) {
      conv.ask('Which color would you like to hear about?');
    } else if (repromptCount === 1) {
      conv.ask(`Please say the name of a color.`);
    } else if (conv.arguments.get('IS_FINAL_REPROMPT')) {
      conv.close(`Sorry we're having trouble. Let's ` +
        `try this again later. Goodbye.`);
    }
  });    

module.exports = server;
```

My **NodeJs** application just consists of **index.js** and **package.json**.
I did an `npm install` and then ftped the two files and node_modules to my azure web application. When I tested my google actions application, it gets a webhook error because it can't communicate.

Can someone tell me what I need to do to get it to work?

PS: This is my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "pyb-actions",
  "description": "Actions on Google for PYB",
  "author": "r3plica",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "npm run shell"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "i18n": "^0.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.19.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.9.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer this question if you could share the error message you're seeing.

Comment: Please post more information about error or web.config. Maybe your issue at here is the same with your other SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633043/publish-an-express-server-to-azure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a simpel get-route to test if the problem is related to your server setup or the way you initialize the app.

```
app.get('/', function(request,response) {
  response.json({
    "response": "The server is runnning"
  });
});
```

Or, try to forward your localhost via [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) and use that as temporary fulfillment webhook.

Here's my index.js for inspiration:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google')
const intents = require('./intents')

const expressApp = express().use(bodyParser.json())
const app = dialogflow()

app.intent('Welcome', intents.welcome)

expressApp.post('/fulfill', (req, resp) => app)

expressApp.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log("server starting " + (process.env.PORT || 3000));
})
```

Hope it helps