# Publish an express server to azure

Tags: azure, express

I am new to **nodejs**. I have a very simple express application (comprises of just one javascript file (index.js) and looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {
  dialogflow
} = require('actions-on-google');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const app = dialogflow({
  debug: true
});
const server = express()
  .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }))
  .use(bodyParser.json(), app)
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));
```

When I publish this to azure I generate a web.config file with this setting:

```
-Handler iisnode -NodeStartFile index.js -appType node
```

which generates a web.config like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
    IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

    https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: What azure service do you have questions about? Azure App Service?

Comment: Based on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs) and my experience, you don't have to generate a web config file. It should be auto generated for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you copied the content of the `web.config` file from [`Using a custom web.config for Node apps`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps) and replace the first `server.js` value with `index.js` in code `<add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>`.

However, there are two other `server.js` values which also need to be replaced in the tag `rewrite`, as below.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
    <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^index.js\/debug[\/]?" /> // Replace `server.js` at here
    </rule>

    <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
    <rule name="StaticContent">
      <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
    </rule>

    <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
    <rule name="DynamicContent">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js"/> // Replace `server.js` at here
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

After replaced all of `server.js` with `index.js`, to restart your webapp and refresh your page in browser, then you can see that it works.

Note: The default Node.js version on Azure WebApp is `0.10.40`, so first you need to change its version via set the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` value in application settings, please see my answer for the SO thread [Azure NodeJS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034084/azure-nodejs-version/54070657#54070657) to know how to do.

Comment: I noticed that myself and I changed it. I have restarted my webapp and it doesn't work. I feel that maybe I am not uploading all the required files. To clarify, I need to upload index.js, web.config and the node_modules folder. I assume there is no need to upload the package.json file?

Comment: @r3plica Sure. The `package.json` file is not required. Did you set the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` value in application settings to change the default node version `0.10.40`? Please refer to my answer for the SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034084/azure-nodejs-version/54070657#54070657.

Comment: It's funny, you keep saying stuff just after I implement them :) I already set the node version but the test is still not working :( I get a HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

Comment: for reference, I set node to 10.15.1

Comment: in kudu when I run node -v I get: v0.10.40